# Change android "sublayout" depending on object state

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout, where the top quarter is always the same, but the lower part needs to use a "sublayout" specific to the represented object's state.

Can I achieve this, using a "parent" layout and several state-specific layouts?

(The state-specific layouts could either be embedded in the parent layout at run-time, or each child layout could "include" the parent layout.)

Comment: Why cant you use a list view with a header and one child, And for the reference object to the row will have a state which will decide the type of view to be shown.

Comment: This would have been an unnecessary complication, especially as the state-specific sublayout needs to handle clicks itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be straightforward, once I'd added a placeholder-view to the LinearLayout (at index 2).

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    int stateLayout;
    switch (peer.commState) {
        case IDLE:
            stateLayout = R.layout.peer_idle;
            break;
        case REQUEST_MADE:
            stateLayout = R.layout.peer_request_made;
            break;
        ...
        default:
            throw new AssertionError();
    }

    linearLayout.removeViewAt(2);
    View stateView = inflater.inflate(stateLayout, linearLayout, false);
    linearLayout.addView(stateView);
```